# Abstract Functions in Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to have 'abstract functions' in python without a base class? I'm not sure if this is the correct terminology for this, but I'd essentially like to somehow force a set of utility functions to conform to some type of signature.

For example, in the following example I would like to use that @someSignature decorator to force any function tagged with it to take those two parameters and return true or false. How can I do that?

```
@someSignature
def perform_action(user, object):
    return True

@someSignature
def perform_action_2(user, object):
    return False
```

Comment: Read on python typing https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: You should add a bit more context, as in, how would you like to use that constraint. If your goal is for your IDE to warn you when you provide a wrong function as a parameter, then Python typing can do it for you. I'm not sure about other use cases.

Comment: I'm unclear on the use case you have in mind.  It seems that you want to hijack the given function and substitute another -- which is legal and straightforward, but I don't see how it's supposed to work in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Typically decorators don't actually execute until you call the function. So yes, you could get a warning when you run it and you've defined it with too many parameters, but I can't see a case where this would be helpful. In the decorator you could cast the result to `bool` to get specifically `True` or `False.

```
def some_signature(fun):
  def wrapper(*args):
    if len(args) == 2:
      return bool(fun(*args))
    raise ValueError('This function may only take two arguments.')
  return wrapper


@some_signature
def foo(u, o):
  return u == o


@some_signature
def bar(u, o, b):
   return u == o == b


foo(1, 1)
# => True

bar(1, 1, 1)
# => ValueError: This function may only take two arguments.
```

---

I think what would be more useful would be to type the function, or presumably what's going to happen here is the function will be passed as an argument. Then you can type the argument.

```
from typing import Any, Callable

def higher_order_fun(fun: Callable[[Any, Any], bool]) -> bool:
  return fun(1, 2)
```